# Combobox selectedValue change all items properties

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, mvvm

I've got a listview with "Cars" and a combobox which display the "Gas" of the listview SelectedCar :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CarList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GasList}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCar.Gas.ID}"
             SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
```

My MainViewModel manage the "CarList" and "SelectedCar" properties:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Car> CarList { get; set; }

    private Car selectedCar;
    public Car SelectedCar
    {
        get { return selectedCar; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedCar != value)
            {
                selectedCar = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCar");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        IList<Car> tempList;

        using (var ctx = new CarDBFirstEntities())
        {

            var car = ctx.Cars
                .Include("Gas")
                .ToList();

            tempList = (IList<Car>)car;
        }


        CarList = new ObservableCollection<Car>();

        //Convert LINQ list to ObservableCollection
        foreach (Car c in tempList)
            CarList.Add(v);

    }
}
```

My CarViewModel (which is called from my window) is derived from MainViewModel and manage "GasList" property:

```
public class CarViewModel : MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Gas> GasList { get; set; }

    public CarViewModel()
    {
        IList<Gas> tempList;

        using (var ctx = new CarDBFirstEntities())
        {
            var gas = ctx.Gas.ToList();

            tempList = (IList<Gas>)gas;
        }

        GasList = new ObservableCollection<Gas>();

        //Convert LINQ list to ObservableCollection
        foreach (Gas g in tempList)
            GasList.Add(g);

    }
}
```

I use EF 6 so here are my auto-generated poco proxies class :

```
public partial class Car
{
    ...
    public Nullable<int> GasID { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual Gas Gas{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Gas
{
    public Gas()
    {
        this.Car = new HashSet<Car>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Well, When I select a car in my listview, the combobox display the gas name of the car.
The problem is when I change the value in the combobox, all the cars which had the same gas are updated.
Here is an exemple :
I've got 2 cars with the same gas value ("gas").
I select the first one in my listView and change the combobox value (to "diesel" for exemple).
Then if I select the second one in my listview the combobox is displaying "diesel" too.

As I can understand, my combobox is just changing the ID of the Gas and not the ID of the SelectedCar.Gas so the probleme come from here (I guess).

I tried many things like replacing "SelectedValue" by "SelectedItem" in my combobox and it's working if I [override the equals method](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/) in my poco proxy Gas class but it's an auto-generated class so I don't think it's the good way.

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: This is just a reference.  foreach (Gas g in tempList) GasList.Add(g);  Need to new for each car.

Comment: Thank's for your answer but I don't see what you mean here?

Comment: Add a Gas ctor to Gas.  foreach (Gas g in tempList) GasList.Add(new Gas(g));

Comment: I tried that but nothing changes

Comment: Ok that was that :) thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that was the answer

This is just a reference.

```
foreach (Gas g in tempList) GasList.Add(g);
```

Need to new for each car.

Add a Gas ctor to Gas.

```
foreach (Gas g in tempList) GasList.Add(new Gas(g));
```